# Background image hover effect outside of containing element

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a background image hover effect on each row in my css table but need it to appear to the left of the containing element.

[View image http://www.weiserwebworld.com/images/view.gif](http://www.weiserwebworld.com/images/view.gif)

Any ideas?

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".table-row").hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    })
})
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 660px; 
    margin: 20px auto;
}

div .table {
    display: table;
    border: 1px red solid;  
}
div .table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
div .table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;

}
.highlight {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('click-to-view.png');
    background-position: 0 center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">Ralph Kramden</div>
            <div class="table-cell">Truck Driver</div>
            <div class="table-cell">8/17/2010</div>
            <div class="table-cell">N/A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">Ralph Kramden</div>
            <div class="table-cell">Truck Driver</div>
            <div class="table-cell">8/17/2010</div>
            <div class="table-cell">N/A</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to point this out: for a table of data, you should be using a `<table>`, not zillions of `div`s with `display: table*`. A `<table>` is the correct choice, semantically.

Comment: This is true but this is a simplified version of the real code. Using tables is not practical with the real code we are also using.

Comment: @YourBudWeiser: if you're using things like `display: table-*`, you clearly don't care about IE6. So stop using jQuery to add a .highlight class and start using `:hover` in your CSS!

Comment: What browsers and versions does this need to support?

Comment: I am supporting IE8 and up, Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, throw away this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".table-row").hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    })
})
```

It is an abomination.

Then change the CSS selector `.highlight` to `.table-row:hover`. As you clearly don't care about IE6 (where `:hover` only worked on `a` elements), there's nothing wrong with using `:hover`.

Now to the rest of the problem.

---

The technique that I would use for this is the `before` or `after` pseudo-element. Something like this:

```
.table-row {
    position: relative; /* So that the position: absolute on the "click to view" makes it relative to the table row */
}
.table-row:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -80px; /* Adjust as desired */
    content: url(click-to-view.png); /* This makes it an image */
}
```

There's plenty of tweaking that can be done with this, but that's the general idea. No demo on jsfiddle as I can't be bothered doing the table structure or getting an image for it.

Comment: I would have also gone the pseudo-element route, however it doesn't work in this scenario with `display:table-row`. It stays relative to the window and not the `.table-row`.

Comment: Doesn't it? I would have thought that it would. Wonder if that could be a browser bug. Going to bed now, but I'll put it on my list of Things to Investigate when I Have Time (Which Will be Never).

Comment: Lol, you're a funny guy Chris! This does indeed work. The left position in the example pushes the image off of the screen but just change the left to a positive number and there it is. Thanks!

Comment: @yourbudweiser: What browser are you testing in? In Firefox 6 it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS.

This is quick and dirty, you'll have to tweak it to how you want, but the general idea is:

If you give your row an id () you can add a CSS styles like this:

```
.overlay {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: -30px; //makes it appear left of box, even though it's technically "in" box.
}

#table-row1:hover .overlay {
    display; block;  //Causes div to appear.
}
```

Now, simply add  with the image you want, that will appear as you roll over the row.

Note that the class=overlay div MUST be placed INSIDE of the id=table-row1 div or the hover-appear will not work!

I would also recommend redoing this using  tags with the same :hover approach, as your current method of divs with table properties could get unwieldy very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your image in a DIV, then position the DIV relative to the row. Backgrounds cannot go outside the boundary of their container.